# How to convert value's in DF by loop?

Tags: python

I have data set with string column and I had to convert them into int value the problem is some columns have 90+ different value and to convert them 
manually and take time, there is a function to solve it automatically?

I did it, but manually:

```
price_dict = {91:0, 65:1, 0:1, 20:1, 35:1, 32:1, 41:1, 36:1, 15:1, 90:1, 6:1, 67:1, 2:1, 57:1, 39:1, 1:1, 79:1, 34:1, 85:1} # not all

app[`Price`] = app[`Price`].apply(lambda a: price_dict[a]) # 0 = free, 1 = not free

app[`Price`].value_counts() # To check.
```

I have tried :

```
 for x in app[`Price`]:

        if x == 1:
            price_dict = {91:0}
        else:
            price_dict = {x:1}

app[`Price`] = app[`Price`].apply(lambda a: price_dict[a])# 0 = free, 1 = not free

app[`Price`].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to transform a column using a dictionary to define the transformation:

```
price_dict = {91:0, 65:1, 0:1, 20:1, 35:1, 32:1, 41:1, 36:1, 15:1, 90:1, 6:1, 67:1, 2:1, 57:1, 39:1, 1:1, 79:1, 34:1, 85:1} # not all

app['Price'] = app['Price'].map(price_dict)

app['Price'].value_counts()
```

You can also replace values in columns like this:

```
app['Price_new'] = 1

app.loc[app.Price == 91, 'Price_new'] = 0
```